# Mysql update if

Tags: mysql, if-statement

this is the query i am trying to use.

```
  SET @id = 289;
    SET @feedId = 5;
    SET @statusid = 2;
    SET @processId = 1;

    SET @feedIdExists = (
     SELECT EXISTS (
       SELECT *
       FROM feed_statuses
       WHERE FeedId = @feedId));

    IF feedIdExists = 1 THEN
     UPDATE `snap`.`feed_statuses` 
      SET
      `ProcessId` = @processId , 
      `StatusId` = @statusId , 
      `ProcessEndDate` = NOW()
      WHERE
      `FeedId` = @feedId;
    ELSE
     INSERT INTO `snap`.`feed_statuses` 
      (`FeedId`, 
      `ProcessId`, 
      `StatusId`, 
      `ProcessStartDate`
      )
      VALUES 
      (@feedId,
      @processId,
      @statusId,
      NOW());
    END IF;
```

hi guys,
there are 3 errors about the if syntax.
i didnt understand.
why doesnt it work properly?

9 queries executed, 6 success, 3 errors, 0 warnings

Query: use snap

0 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0.001 sec
Transfer Time  : 0.001 sec

### Total Time     : 0.002 sec

Query: SET @id = 289

0 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0.001 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec

### Total Time     : 0.001 sec

Query: SET @feedId = 5

0 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0.002 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec

### Total Time     : 0.002 sec

Query: SET @statusid = 2

0 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0.002 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec

### Total Time     : 0.002 sec

Query: SET @processId = 1

0 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0.002 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec

### Total Time     : 0.002 sec

Query: SET @feedIdExists = ( SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM feed_statuses WHERE FeedId = @feedId))

0 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0.002 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec

### Total Time     : 0.002 sec

Query: IF feedIdExists = 1 THEN UPDATE `snap`.`feed_statuses` SET `ProcessId` = @processId , `StatusId` = @statusId , `ProcessEndDate` ...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF feedIdExists = 1 THEN
     UPDATE `snap`.`feed_statuses` 
      SET
      `Pr' at line 1

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec

### Total Time     : 0.002 sec

Query: ELSE INSERT INTO `snap`.`feed_statuses` (`FeedId`, `ProcessId`, `StatusId`, `ProcessStartDate` ) VALUES (@feedId, @processId, @s...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSE
     INSERT INTO `snap`.`feed_statuses` 
      (`FeedId`, 
      `ProcessId' at line 1

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec

### Total Time     : 0.002 sec

Query: END IF

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 1

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.002 sec

Comment: Paste the errors you get. Without them someone first have to figure out what the problem is and then solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Insert ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` to resolve this issue.

**Note**: you must have `UNIQUE` key first, And I think you have it.

```
INSERT INTO `snap`.`feed_statuses` 
  (`FeedId`, 
  `ProcessId`, 
  `StatusId`, 
  `ProcessStartDate`
  )
  VALUES 
  (@feedId,
  @processId,
  @statusId,
  NOW());
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE
  `ProcessId` = @processId , 
  `StatusId` = @statusId , 
  `ProcessEndDate` = NOW()
```

You must check this: [INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: what if I want to check if it is 2 for example

Comment: In your question you only check if exist, And this answer for your problem.
The link I provide for you has the full documentation for this operation. 
So I do not understand where you will check if it is 2 ?